# A puzzle about circles

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

This is a simple visual enigmatic puzzle I created myself.

It contains 2400 squares mainly colored using 3 colors, and there are two highlighted squares.

Your task is to identify what each color represents, and what relationship to circles does the theme of the answers have.

[image]

---

> in the original image the interpretation of the coordinate digits is left deliberately ambiguous, so that there is a column that doesn't quite fit. Now it is fixed.

Comment: Hint: this puzzle is related to coordinates.

Comment: Should the rot13(gjraglavargu pbyhza bs gur guveq ebj ) maybe colored in cyan or is it irrelevant?

Comment: @theozh actually, rot13(ab, gurfr juvgr pryyf ercerfrag gur znkvzhz cbffvoyr yratgu bs gur erfcrpgvir vgrzf), I think you know what the image represents. Please post an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the intended interpretation and whether it is complete or if there is more behind it:
So, maybe somebody can give a clearer picture.

Maybe...

> - the 24 rows present the 24 hours of a day 
> - the 100 columns represent 100 years in a century 
>  - the 60 columns which are colored cyan (neglecting the white cells) represent the 60 minutes in an hour 
>  - the white rows have a different lengths (i.e. number of columns) from 29 to 31 
>  - from row 1 (counting from 0) to row 12 the lengths coincide with the number of days in the 12 months in a year (February with 29 days)

The magenta colored cells:

> The 7th column (counting from 1) of the 11th white row:  
>  This should probably represent November 7th, the date of posting this puzzle.  
>   
>  The 23rd column of the 20th row (counting from 0):  
> this should probably direct to the year 2023

In summary:

> **Topic: Date and Time**  
>  Date: Earth is moving around the sun in a circle (actually, ellipse)  
>  Time: Hands of a clock running in circles

Comment: Your answer is correct but incomplete. The colors were chosen using additive color mixing. The picture can be thought of as a Venn diagram. Try expressing the quantities using pairs of two digit numbers and you will see.